# Monitor/Mwait instructions for multiple addresses at once?

Tags: c, x86, wait, cpu-architecture, monitor

I have verified the usage of Monitor/Mwait instruction when monitoring a single address. But I want to know whether it can monitor multiple addresses simultaneously. And how many addresses can be monitored at the same time?

For example, I try to monitor variable a and variable b with the following code, and I find the processor can wake up when a or b changes. Is there any official instruction on how to monitor multiple addresses with Monitor/Mwait.

```
monitor(&a, 0, 0);
monitor(&b, 0, 0);
mwait(0, 0);
```

Comment: I'd say it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Only one address can be monitored at a time. Executing the MONITOR instruction replaces the previously monitored address.

It doesn't monitor a single byte address, though; it is a range. The size of the range can be discovered using CPUID.
It is generally 64 bytes (a single cache line). That explains why you observed it triggering on both a and b.